# Keep a list from provider up to date with AnimatedListView

Tags: flutter, flutter-animation

I'm using the `Provider` library and have a class that extends `ChangeNotifier`. The class provides an `UnmodifiableListView` of `historicalRosters` to my widgets.

I want to create an `AnimatedListView` that displays these rosters. The animated list supposedly needs a separate list which will tell the widget when the widget to animate in or out new list items.

```dart
final GlobalKey<AnimatedListState> _listKey = GlobalKey<AnimatedListState>();
```

[This example](https://flutter.dev/docs/catalog/samples/animated-list) uses a model to update both the list attached to the widget's state and the AnimateListState at the same time.

```dart
// Inside model
void insert(int index, E item) {
  _items.insert(index, item);
  _animatedList.insertItem(index);
}
```

I want to do the same thing but I'm having trouble thinking how. That is, what's a good way I can update the list provided by `provider` and also change the `AnimatedListState`.

Answer (score 0):

when you call updateListAndAnimate from your widget or elsewhere, it should ensure that both the list provided by Provider and the AnimatedListState are updated simultaneously.

import 'package:flutter/foundation.dart';

class YourChangeNotifierClass extends ChangeNotifier {
List historicalRosters = []; // Your data list

// AnimatedListState key
final GlobalKey _listKey = GlobalKey();

// Method to update both the list and AnimatedListState
void updateListAndAnimate(YourItemType newItem) {
int index = historicalRosters.length;

```
// Update the data list
historicalRosters.add(newItem);

// Notify listeners to rebuild widgets using the updated list
notifyListeners();

// Update the AnimatedListState
_listKey.currentState?.insertItem(index);
```

}
}